# Knockout data-bind issue

Tags: c#, javascript, knockout.js

I have a dropdownlist with data-bind;

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cmbType" Runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" data-bind="value: moveType">
  <asp:ListItem Value="">-- Please Select --</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="0">Car</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="1">Air</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

also I have

```
var viewModel = {
  this.moveType = ko.observable(MoveType);

};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());​
```

where "MoveType" is 0 or 1. This seems to be working fine but only partly.
Everything is fine and value from dropdown are selected correctly ONLY if "MoveType" = 1. In case if MoveType = 0, it don't want to select "Car" and instead selected option will be "-- Please Select --"  with value "".

The question is simple, why? What am I missing? I can't understand it.

Comment: Huh? What do you expect the `MoveType` observable to be if the user selects "Car" at some point?

Comment: Can you explain this more clearly.. either am unable to understand or this seems to be ambiguous..

Comment: Create a new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Jeroen - didn't understand you at all.

Answer (score 0):

Are You sure that You are not getting any errors in console?

I changed your code into :

```
var MoveType=1;
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.moveType = ko.observable(MoveType);       
};    
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

and now its seems to work:
you can test it [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8v3nL1pg/)

Comment: Yes I'm sure. But thanks for your example. I fixed applyBindings in my question. Didn't spot out that I placed ViewModel in question without "new".

Answer (score 0):

"car" has a value of `0` in your drop down list (look at your `Value` attributes). That is why `0` causes "car" to be selected. If you want to select "-- Please Select --", you need to set the value to an empty string `""`.

This in turn implies that your javascript `moveType` and thus also your C# `MoveType` must be a string rather than a number, since "" is not a valid number.

To prevent that I suggest you number your options differently: use `Value="1"` for car and `Value="2"` for air. Then your "please select" option gets `Value="0"`.

Comment: Thanks for answer but, did you read a question? The problem is that value "" is selected instead of "0" (When MoveType is 0).

Comment: @Olegs - I did read the question but it was not clear enough. But did you read my answer? I mean, paragraphs 2 and 3?